# Can items be swapped between team members in Shadowrun: Dragonfall?

Tags: shadowrun-dragonfall

I'd like to transfer consumable items such as medkits between my party members during a run. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not move items between members of your team.

But as a stop gap, when you are in the mission & during combat you can pick up items from the level with other characters.

I've personally used a melee character with pommel strike to hit their last soldier and reduce their AP and stun them turn after turn.  This allowed the rest of my team to raid lockers and medical kits to resupply.  It was kinda necessary on the hardest skill level.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately this feature wasn't added until Shadowrun: Hong Kong, the next game in the series. In Dragonfall you can arrange things at the start of a mission only.

In Dragonfall you can use medkits out of combat and choose who they apply to, so it's not too bad for those. You can use them strategically this way to try to make sure that the characters who might need to use one in combat as an emergency have still got theirs.

Source: I recently played through Dragonfall again after playing Hong Kong and I was slightly annoyed to be reminded I couldn't do this. :)